# Spring boot: Build an uri "/{id}" using ServletUriComponentsBuilder

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Currently, I'm using this code snippet in order to create a uri reference:

```
URI uri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder
    .fromCurrentContextPath()
    .path(EspaiDocConstants.Endpoints.DOWNLOAD)
    .path(attributes.getId())
    .build()
    .toUri();
```

However, it genertes:

```
http://localhost:8080/downlo**adcp**d4-6b9f27c1-e9b3-4735-8127-8f18724734e9
```

Between `**adcp**` there's not any slash!

How could I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `path()` just concatenates strings. You can add a slash by your own

```
.path(EspaiDocConstants.Endpoints.DOWNLOAD)
.path("/")
.path(attributes.getId())
```